# Existence of injective hull

Tags: reference-request, modules, homological-algebra

Is that true that every module over a ring has an injective hull?

The term "has an injective hull" appears in several different contexts, some of them say that modules over a ring has this property (by looking on Google) and specially on Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull) we have the claim "Every module M has an injective hull. The dual notion of a projective cover does not always exist for a module, however a flat cover exists for every module." How to prove it? What is a reference with this Theorem?

Comment: The answer to this question is in the first paragraph of the wikipedia article.

Comment: How to prove *what*? The sentence you quoted has three completely different claims, one extremely nontrivial. The injective hull is constructed in shelves of algebra books. Existences of projective covers are treated in Anderson and Fuller's book and Lam's books, to name a few. The Flat Cover Conjecture was proved in the 1980's, and requires quite a bit of technique to show.

Comment: Flat Cover Conjecture was proved in around 99 :-) Ed Enochs conjectured it around 1980, and finished it up in time to teach it to us in 2000.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh?! I definitely forgot how late it was proven then. I must have confounded it with the time of statement. I knew it was hard. Do you have good notes/exposition on a proof?

Comment: @rschweib Chapter 7 of Enochs–Jenda (2001) looks more or less like what we did. 7.4.4 is the theorem itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to learn about injective hulls, for example,

- Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings* starting around page 75.
- Matsumura's [Commutative ring theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=yJwNrABugDEC&pg=PA281&dq=%22injective+hull%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qvv_UeWAKbCayQGYoIHIDw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20hull%22&f=false) page 281.
- Or in Goodearl's [Introuction to Noncommutative Noetherian rings](http://books.google.com/books?id=vXh1MtvQr_8C&pg=PA94&dq=injective+hull&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jvb_UfGMIvLiyAHThIHwAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=injective%20hull&f=false) around page 94.
- Or in [Wisbauer's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=iLwb9FWNRSwC&pg=PA141&dq=injective+hull&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yPb_UfeUIuiayAGN8oBQ&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=injective%20hull&f=false) around page 141.
- [Rowen's Ring theory book](http://books.google.com/books?id=ud8MV2C76RYC&pg=PA218&dq=%22injective+hull%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e_z_Ubm3N6uyygGjyYCYDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20hull%22&f=false) around page 218.
- Or around page 94 of [Lambek's algebra book](http://books.google.com/books?id=dQjEsZFyFXQC&pg=PA170&dq=%22injective+hull%22+bourbaki&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fvf_UfiPMqaIygHJtICYAg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20hull%22%20&f=false).
- Anderson and Fuller's *Rings and categories of modules*, ( Theorem 18.10 page 207 Thanks Jack Schmidt!)
- somewhere in *Commutative Algebra: With a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*
- Bourbaki books, but I can't lay my hand on pages atm.
- You can read about them also in D.G. Northcott's [Homological algebra books](http://books.google.com/books?id=9Q44AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA37&dq=%22injective+envelope%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xvj_Uba1OuyAygHNroDwCw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20envelope%22&f=false) starting page 37.
- [Grillet's algebra book](http://books.google.com/books?id=LJtyhu8-xYwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22injective+hull%22+grillet&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yfr_UfqZLpT8yAGCzIDwDg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20hull%22&f=false) somewhere
- You can also read about very interesting things concerning these topics in Faith's [*Rings and Things*](http://books.google.com/books?id=1TfVy2AD3PkC&pg=PA54&dq=%22injective+hull%22+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zPf_Uen4B-yuyAHS5oHoDQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20hull%22%20algebra&f=false) starting around page 54.

The Flat Cover Conjecture was no trivial thing, and you can [read about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_cover#Flat_resolutions).

The rings for which all right modules have a projective cover are called right [perfect rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring), which you can read about in Anderson and Fuller or Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*.

Comment: Anderson–Fuller Theorem 18.10 page 207

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks, I'll cite you citing him. Where should I send the check?